# How to automatically restart pods when a new image ready

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I'm using K8s on GCP.

Here is my deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: simpleapp-direct
  labels:
    app: simpleapp-direct
    role: backend
    stage: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: simpleapp-direct
      version: v0.0.1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: simpleapp-direct
        version: v0.0.1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: simpleapp-direct
          image: gcr.io/applive/simpleapp-direct:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

I first apply the deployment file with kubectl apply command

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

The pods were created properly.

I was expecting that every time I would push a new image with the tag latest, the pods would be automatically killed and restart using the new images.

I tried the rollout command

```
kubectl rollout restart deploy simpleapp-direct
```

The pods restart as I wanted.

However, I don't want to run this command every time there is a new latest build.
How can I handle this situation ?.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Try to use image hash instead of tag in your Pod Definition.

Generally: there is no way to automatically restart pods when the new image is ready. It is generally advisable not to use image:latest (or just image_name) in Kubernetes as it can cause difficulties with rollback of your deployment. Also you need to make sure that the flag: imagePullPolicy is set to Always. Normally when you use CI/CD or git-ops your deployment is updated automatically by these tools when the new image is ready and passed thru the tests.

When your Docker image is updated, you need to setup a trigger on this update within your CI/CD pipilne to re-run the deployment. Not sure about the base system/image where you build your docker image, but you can add there kubernetes certificates and run the above commands like you do on your local computer.

Comment: do you have an example ?

Comment: Sorry, after having more thorough read of your question. There is no way to automatically restart pods when the new image is ready. It is generally advisable not to use image:latets in Kubernetes as it can cause difficulties with rollback of your deployment. Also you need to make sure that the flag: imagePullPolicy is set to Always. Normally when you use CI/CD or git-ops your deployment is updated automatically by these toolds when the new image is ready and passed thru the tests.

Comment: The thing is I have a VPC and I'm using bitbucket to store the source. I setup bitbucket-pipeline to deploy build test and deploy image in GCP image container registry. Bitbucket don't have direct access to the cluster since it a private one.

Comment: Ok, you need to setup a trigger in your pipilne to re-run the deployment. Not sure about the base system/image where you build your docker image, but you can add there kubernetes certificates and run the above commands like you do on your local computer.

Comment: @yurasov, this is very good explanation. Can you please merge your comments into your answers?

Comment: This kind of sucks if the CI/CD that builds the images has no access to the kube clusters.